# Why my app containing listView is crashing?

Tags: android

My app contains only 2 files one is MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml file. I wanted to use to listView to display a list of string but for some my app is crashing continuously.

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("Akshay");
    arrayList.add("Akshay");
    arrayList.add("Akshay");
    arrayList.add("Akshay");
    arrayList.add("Pandey");
    arrayList.add("Akshay");
    arrayList.add("Akshay");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,0,arrayList);
    ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is crashing because you are passing `0` as the second argument to your `ArrayAdapter` constructor. This is the "layout resource id" that your list will use for each item, so it needs to be something real.

The Android platform comes with some resources for this purpose built in, like `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. You could try that. Change this line:

> ```
> ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,0,arrayList);
> ```

to this instead:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
```

More information can be found in the developer guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the second argument of `ArrayAdapter` to `0`. The constructor expects a valid resource. You need to set it to something like this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.my_resource_view, arrayList);
```